# MFC71.DLL was not found error

Tags: windows-xp

**Issue**

I am trying to fix an issue with a friend's Windows XP laptop.  Immediately after booting, a popup box titled `bcmwltry.exe - Unable to Locate Component` appears, with the following text in it:

> This application has failed to start because MFC71.DLL was not found. 
>   Re-installing the application may fix this problem.

If I click `OK` then another popup appears, titled `WLTRAY.exe - Unable to Locate Component` with the same text in it:

> This application has failed to start because MFC71.DLL was not found. 
>   Re-installing the application may fix this problem.

If I click `OK` again, then the aforementioned popup boxes keep appearing again each time I press OK.
I also noticed a link on the desktop titled `Shortcut to MFC71.dll`

**What I have tried**

1. Running `sfc /scannow`, to "verify that all protected Windows files are intact and in their original versions."
2. Running a disk defragmentation.
3. Running a disk cleanup
4. Restarting the computer
5. Going into the Securiy Center via Control Panel, I noticed that there is no antivirus program installed, not even windows defender.  I went online to attempt to download Windows Defender and even CCeaner.  When I went to www.google.com, "the page could not be displayed", but I was able to search through Bing on the msn.com homepage which loaded. I attempted to search for CCleaner and Windows Defender, but although search results were displayed, their pages were not responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by first starting the computer in safe mode (F8 on startup).  I then went under the `start menu > all programs > System Recovery > Application and Driver Recovery`
This launched Gateway's (manufacturer of this comuter) Application Recovery Program.  From there, I reinstalled the Broadcom Gemtek Wireless abg driver, and the .Net Framework 2.0, then restarted the computer.
The reason I did this is because bcmwltry.exe is used for Broadcom Corporation Wireless Network software, and MFC71.DLL is used by .NET.